# How to retrieve the number of violations for a specific rule in Sonar via API?

Tags: sonarqube

I want to retrieve the number of violation for a given rule on a project, using the SonarQube web-service API.

When browsing [the documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743280), the `resources` API, in addition of the `rules` parameter seems to be the answer.

With a URL such as `http://mysonar:9000/api/resources?resource=1&rules=true` or `http://mysonar:9000/api/resources?resource=1&rules=checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.IllegalCatchCheck`, I get the following XML:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <id>1</id>
        <key>foo:bar</key>
        <name>Foo</name>
        <lname>Foo</lname>
        <scope>PRJ</scope>
        <qualifier>TRK</qualifier>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <date>2014-05-26T15:42:14+0200</date>
        <creationDate>2014-05-26T15:42:14+0200</creationDate>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

So, how can I retrieve this kind of information?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sonar suppor team, I found the solution.
The `rules` parameter works only when the `metrics` parameter is set to a specific severity for violations, such as `major_violations`:

http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?resource=140632&metrics=major_violations&rules=true